# Anylogic java Querydsl wrong result with and()

Tags: java, anylogic, querydsl

I have the database `c2d_selfpickup` in the Anylogic model:

[image]

I have to find the c2d_lm value by `SCid` and `PVZid` using QueryDSL:

```
List <Double> c2dlmList = selectFrom(c2d_selfpickup)
                            .where(c2d_selfpickup.sc_id.goe(SCid)
                            .and( c2d_selfpickup.pvz_id.goe(PVZid) ))
                            .list(c2d_selfpickup.c2d_lm);
```

If I choose the next pair:

```
int SCid = 256151;
int PVZid = 547307;
```

I expect that the query returns `c2dlmList` with one value `8.0` (the row number 8), but it returns 7 values:

```
[2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 8.0, 10.0]
```

What I do wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result is actually correct. The query considers all entries in the database, so it will return all rows where `sc_id >= 256,151` and `pvz_id >= 547,307` (goe = greater or equal).

In case you only want to get the row that exactly matches both conditions, you may want to use `eq()` instead of `goe()`.